# Use proxy IP with a ruby script

Tags: ruby, macos, proxy, webserver, ip

I am trying to run a ruby script from my computer and I would like to have the script use a proxy IP address / server that I have setup, as opposed to the default IP address associated with my local machine.

I have been able to get my web browsers to use this proxy IP address by making changes inside network settings. But When I run the ruby script from textmate, it doesn't seem to use the proxy IP address I have put into my network settings. Instead it defaults back to the base ip address of my local machine.

Is there anything I can do in textmate or in the script itself to specify a proxy IP address it should route through?

My script looks like the following:

```
require "open-uri"
url = "some-url"
pattern = "<img"   


page = open(url).read
tags = page.scan(pattern)
puts "The site #{url} has #{tags.length} img tags"
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmm, are you developing under mac os? If so, please add this tag :)

Comment: yes - on a mac, if that's what you mean - will add tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `:proxy` option to let open-uri know your proxy server:

```
page = open(url, :proxy => "http://#{proxy_host}:#{proxy_port}/").read
```

You can also set environment variable `http_proxy` instead. If you do so, give `:proxy => true` for option.

```
page = open(url, :proxy => true).read
```

[ADDED]

If you want to use proxy with basic authentication, you can give `:proxy_http_basic_authentication` option instead of `:proxy` as follows:

```
:proxy_http_basic_authentication => ["http://#{proxy_host}:#{proxy_port}/", login, password]
```

Note that `:proxy_http_basic_authentication` can be used in ruby **1.9.2 or later**.

Comment: Cool - this makes sense. Is there a clean easy way to pass in a username and password for the proxy server?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using mechanize, and css instead of regex:

```
require "mechanize"
url = "http://www.google.com/"

@agent = Mechanize.new{|a| a.set_proxy 'localhost', 8888}
page = @agent.get url
tags = page.search('img')
puts "The site #{url} has #{tags.length} img tags"
```